# Replace a text and save in a new file text - Python

Tags: python

They are the first Python weapons and I would need to create a simple script that takes all text files in input (a folder of choice).

For each text file, delete line "# Constructed from biom file" and replace "#OTU ID" with "OTU_ID".

Then save it to another text file that keeps the first portion of the file name and then adds "_mod.txt" to the end of the file name.

The script must perform all these operations automatically for all the files in the directory.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#
import os,sys,uuid
#

with open("/home/antonino/Scrivania/Prove_python/otu_table_filtered_L1.txt","r") as input: # Apro il file di testo
    with open("/home/antonino/Scrivania/Prove_python/otu_table_filtered_L1.txt","wb") as output: # Creo un nuovo file modificato
        for line in input:  
            print line # alvo tutte le linee diverse da # Constructed from....
            if line!="# Constructed from biom file"+"\n":   
                newline = line.replace('OTU ID', 'OTU_ID')
                output.write(newline)
                os.rename("/home/antonino/Scrivania/Prove_python/otu_table_filtered_L1_mod.txt",'result_otu_table_filtered_'+str(uuid.uuid4())+'.txt')
```

This works only in this mode, but that's not what I want.

Comment: sorry for the format code

Comment: It's not a good idea to open the same file for reading and writing at the same time. Open the old file for reading and the new file for writing. That's much safer, and that eliminates the `rename` step.

Comment: It's only at university level. Unfortunately I had precise directions in doing so as I said

Comment: Ok. In that case you will need to read the whole file into RAM before you re-open it for writing, because opening a file in write mode truncates it. There _are_ some read-write modes, but you still need to be careful.

Comment: i have no idea :D